# Log Naive Bayes NLP dropping the denominator

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, natural-language, naive-bayes

I'm learning about the the Naive Bayes classification and I don't get what the squiggly alpha sign means and what it means that "Denominator remains constant for given input." Is it because we're comparing different y inputs? Especially when we do log of this don't we subtract probabilities which makes the values more negative and potentially a negative classification instead of positive?

$$
\boxed{
P(y|x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \frac{P(y)\prod_{i=1}^nP(x_i|y)}{P(x_1)\cdot P(x_2)\cdots P(x_n)}\\
\\
\textrm{Now as the denominator remains constant for a given input, we can remove that term:}\\
\\
P(y|x_1,\ldots,x_n) \propto P(y)\prod_{i=1}^nP(x_i|y)
}
$$

Comment: So it's a proportional function in terms of the Y inputs since P(x) is a constant? But on that question the P(y) term disappears. I'm not quite sure how to make sense of it?

Comment: p(y) in the other question is p(x) here